# Add eZ platform CMS to existing Symfony app

Tags: php, symfony, content-management-system, ezpublish

Is it possible to add eZ Platform CMS to existing Symfony app? I need to add cmf to the existing website, and not sure if only adding to composer `ezsystems/ezplatform` would do the trick? Is it possible to install eZ platform db in existing db?

I'd rather not create new website from ground up based on eZ it self and than add my app bundle to eZ.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not yet ready, but is feasible in the future:

https://twitter.com/andrerom/status/694584143745802240

Comment: That's answer to my Tweet. And I've provided additional question on his answer.